# Specific heat of a two-level quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, two-level-system

> A two-level quantum system has the hamiltonian
>
> $$ H = \begin{pmatrix} E_0 & 0\\ 0 & E_1 \end{pmatrix}
>  + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & g\\ g & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> where $g<<E_0$ and $E_1>E_0$.
>
> Consider a rigid lattice of N sites with one electron each (on
> average) with this Hamiltonian. What is the specific heat of the system for low temperatures?

**Is the following solution right?**

First of all I compute the energy levels. Calling the two energies $\lambda_{0, 1}$ we get

$$
\lambda_{0, 1} = \frac{E_0+E_1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(E_1-E_0)^2+4g^2}
$$

which I can also expand for small g

$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda_0 \approx E_0 -\frac{g^2}{E_1-E_0}\\
\lambda_1 \approx E_1 +\frac{g^2}{E_1-E_0}
\end{cases}
$$

this is also the same result I get with $2^{nd}$ order perturbation theory.

Now since the specific heat is an intensive quantity, I can compute it for one electron only; for this I need the partition function and internal energy, therefore:

$$
Z = e^{-\beta \lambda_0} + e^{-\beta \lambda_1}
$$

$$
U(T) = -\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta} = \frac{\lambda_0 e^{-\beta \lambda_0}+\lambda_1 e^{-\beta \lambda_1}}{e^{-\beta \lambda_0}+e^{-\beta \lambda_1}}
$$

Finally

$$
c_v = \frac{dU}{dT} = \frac{d\beta}{dT}\frac{dU}{d\beta} = -\frac{1}{k_B T^2} \Big[1-\frac{\lambda_0^2 e^{-\beta \lambda_0} + \lambda_1^2 e^{-\beta \lambda_1}}{e^{-\beta \lambda_0} + e^{-\beta \lambda_1}}\Big]
$$

in the limit of small $T$ (and big $\beta$) we get

$$
c_v \approx -\frac{1}{k_B T^2}\Big[1-\frac{\lambda_0^2+\lambda_1^2}{2}\Big]
$$

Is this right? Thanks!

Comment: Just looking at the units of your final expression, something's gone wrong, as you're adding a unitless number to a number with units energy^2